# How does decryption work in mbedtls?

Tags: c, encryption, aes, mbed

I wrote the following simple encryption-decryption program using mbedtls library. Encryption works fine (checked against http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/). However, when decrypting back I get incorrect result (*output2* and *input* are different). Am I misusing the lib?

```
int main()
{
    mbedtls_aes_context aes;
    mbedtls_aes_context aes2;

    unsigned char key[16] = "itzkbgulrcsjmnv";
    key[15] = 'x';

    unsigned char iv[16] = {0xb2, 0x4b, 0xf2, 0xf7, 0x7a, 0xc5, 0xec, 0x0c, 0x5e, 0x1f, 0x4d, 0xc1, 0xae, 0x46, 0x5e, 0x75};

    const unsigned char *input = (const unsigned char*) "Some string to b";
    unsigned char output[128] = {0};
    unsigned char output2[128] = {0};

    mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &aes, key, 16*8 );
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, strlen((const char*)input), iv, input, output );

    mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec( &aes2, key, 16*8 );
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &aes2, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, strlen((const char*)output), iv, output, output2 );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc() function will alter the initialisation vector as it works.  If you expect the same value that was input, you will need to start with the same initialisation vector.

Answer (score 2):

The function mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc() modifies iv's value so that the second call of mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc() does not use the same value. This explains the failure of the decryption.

```
int main()
{
    mbedtls_aes_context aes;
    mbedtls_aes_context aes2;

    unsigned char key[16] = "itzkbgulrcsjmnv";
    key[15] = 'x';

    unsigned char eiv[16] = {0xb2, 0x4b, 0xf2, 0xf7, 0x7a, 0xc5, 0xec, 0x0c, 0x5e, 0x1f, 0x4d, 0xc1, 0xae, 0x46, 0x5e, 0x75};
    unsigned char div[16] = {0xb2, 0x4b, 0xf2, 0xf7, 0x7a, 0xc5, 0xec, 0x0c, 0x5e, 0x1f, 0x4d, 0xc1, 0xae, 0x46, 0x5e, 0x75};

    const unsigned char *input = (const unsigned char*) "Some string to b";
    unsigned char output[128] = {0};
    unsigned char output2[128] = {0};

    mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &aes, key, 16*8 );
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, strlen((const char*)input), eiv, input, output );

    mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec( &aes2, key, 16*8 );
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &aes2, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, strlen((const char*)output), div, output, output2 );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).